# Lock UIDatePicker column

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker with the date mode set, I would like to lock both the Month and Year Selection so that you can only change the day, is this possible?

Comment: You can intercept the touches and check if they are not in the Month and Year sections *before* you pass them through.

Comment: In the `touchesBegin/Moved/Ended` methods, check if the touch is over the Year and Month fields. If it is, don't pass the touch to the `UIDatePicker`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `maximumDate` and `minimumDate` appropriately. Transition between months might be quite the edge case to deal with...

Note that the order of the spinners will vary depending on the locale, so trying to capture the touches is probably a lost cause.

A quick alternative would be to create your own `UIPickerView` that you pass an array of `1...[28-31]` depending on the month / leap year. Might be more intuitive for the user rather then having 2 spinners that they aren't allowed to spin.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of the min/max dates. Yes I may just pass all the days of the month into a single component picker, just didn't want to calculate the days of month  every time.